Completing a full set of cards from a Trading Card Game
In Trading Card Games, cards are edited in sets of $n$ unique cards. These cards are sold in boosters of $k$ random cards. We assume that each card has the same odds of appearing and that in a given booster, cards are unique (you can't get the same card twice in a booster). We also assume that $k$ divides $n$.
What are the odds of completing the set of cards by purchasing only $n/k$ boosters ?
My thought is that there are $n \choose k$ possible boosters.
When you pick the first one, any booster will do, the second time, you have to choose your $k$ cards among the remaining $n-k$, so $n-k \choose k$, the next time you get to choose from the remaining $n-2k$ so $n-2k \choose k$ and so on until $k \choose k$.
So my formula would be
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n/k}\frac{k*i \choose k}{ {n \choose k}}$$
This can be simplified into
$$ \frac{n!}{(k! * {n \choose k})^{n/k}}$$
Is this formula correct ?
It actually happened to me when buying the Trick or Trade pokemon cards. It is a small set of 30 cards sold in boosters of 3 cards and I completed the set after opening only 10 boosters, without getting any repeat.
However, my formula gives odds of around 3.6e-12, which would mean that I literally won the lottery that day !

+1 : Nicely presented question, nice analysis.  I also agree with your answer.

Looks good, and I would also suggest looking at the coupon collector's problem for a treatment of the idea.

Your formula and calculation are correct, on the assumption that each booster packet is equally likely to one of the ${n \choose k}$ possibilities of $k$ distinct types of cards independently of the other booster packets.  So yes, this scenario is extremely unlikely.  But even then it is possible: J. E. Littlewood said a person can expect to experience a "miracle" at the rate of about one per month.
It may be slightly less unlikely is you try to imagine the mechanics of the manufacturer trying to ensure $k$ distinct types in each booster packet.  They cannot just produce a very large number of cards, mix them up and pick $k$ at a time, as this will often produce booster packets with duplicates and it would be expensive to check each individual booster packet for duplicates.  So instead they may produce $n$ distinct cards at a time, mix these up, and make $\frac nk$ packets with $k$ in each; having done this several times they then mix up all the booster packets produced and sell them.
Perhaps something went wrong temporarily in the mixing processes, which resulted in your retailer receiving all $n$ distinct types in $\frac nk$ consecutive booster packets, which you then purchased.

If the first mixing process failed but the second succeeded then there would be $\frac nk$ distinct booster packets instead of ${n \choose k}$ changing the probability to $\frac{(n/k)!}{(n/k)^{(n/k)}}$, which is still small but many orders of magnitude larger than your formula.

If the second mixing process failed but the first succeeded, and you then purchased $\frac nk$ consecutive packets, then the probability might be $\frac kn$ that you purchased what was originally a single batch of $n$ distinct types, which is not small; this could even become $1$ if you started the beginning of a box of booster packets.


You may never know what happened in reality, but the second scenario gives a high likelihood of what you observed and, even if it started with a quite low probability of occurring, it might not be implausible.

Thanks for the different look on the question !
I'm not sure I understood your first point. If there are only $\frac{n}{k}$ possible boosters, wouldn't the odds be $$\frac{(\frac{n}{k})!}{(\frac{n}{k})^{(\frac{n}{k})}}$$
In the meantime, I prefer to believe that I lived a miracle, it makes it more special :-)

@wohlrajh you are correct so I have edited it.  Enjoy your miracle.

Manufacturers do do strange things: for example the game of Dobble/Spot It! could have $57$ cards as a finite projective plane, but in fact has $55$ cards to save money as card printers are optimised for that number.
